# Change Tab using Dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have found the web page below with similar feature, but I am trying to use a dropdown menu instead of a button or A link.

https://jsfiddle.net/Aya_Salama/oyb8smdg/

I think the issue is here: `onchange="$('#'+$this).trigger('click')"`

````
<select class="form-control" onchange="$('#'+$this).trigger('click')">
          <option id="second_tab">Second</option>
          <option id="third_tab">Third</option>
</select>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="$('#second_tab').trigger('click')">Second</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="$('#third_tab').trigger('click')">Third</a>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
<select onchange="$('#'+this.value).trigger('click')">
          <option value="second_tab">Second</option>
          <option value="third_tab">Third</option>
</select>
```